# Generate two no duplicate random numbers in range by Javascript - focus on speed performance

Tags: javascript

I want to generate 1000 objects and put them inside a stack array.

There are 2 random & no duplicate numbers inside object.

The range is from 0 to 4.

I want to find out the method with best performance of speed.

benchmark test score: 34664

```
const stack = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  const range = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
  let r = Math.round(Math.random() * (range.length - 1));
  let x = range[r];
  range.splice(r, 1);
  let y = range[Math.round(Math.random() * (range.length - 1))];
  stack.push({ x: x, y: y });
}
```

benchmark test score: 41618

```
const stack = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    let range = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
    let shuffled = shuffleArray(range);
    let x = shuffled[0];
    let y = shuffled[shuffled.length - 1];
    stack.push({ x: x, y: y });
}

function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
    }
}
```

Comment: You could declare the variables outside the for loop, and then reassign them inside the for loop. How/where do you do your benchmark tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems slow"? Why would you think that? Have you done a benchmark? Is it too slow for your needs? But yes, there are some points to make it correct and faster ...

First of all, `slice` is wrong here, you probably mean `splice`.

Then you are creating a new array in every iteration, that's expensive. Even more so, if you are `splice`ing it also. Better would be, switching elements in the existing array. And finally, you don't need to calc `range.length-1` twice in each iteration. You know the values will be `4` and `3` ...

So I'd do it like this

```
let 
  stack = [], 
  range = [0,1,2,3,4];

for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
  let 
    a = Math.floor(Math.random()* 5),
    b = Math.floor(Math.random()* 4),
    x = range[a];

  range[a] = range[4];
  range[4] = x;

  stack.push({ x, y: range[b]});

}
```

How does it work:

There is only one array with all possible values. First select two random indexes, `a` in the range `[0, 4]` and `b` in the range `[0, 3]`. Then your first random value is the element at index `a`. Now swap the element at index `a` with the last element in the array. Your second random value is now the element at index `b`. The two values must be different, (even if `a === b`)  because `b` can never select the very last element of the array. This is a simple variation of the classic "Fisher-Yates" algorithm ...

Comment: Small note: `stack` is declared as an object, but I assume you mean for it to be an array.

Comment: Excellent answer!  Also notice that if array length is confined to 4 or a small number, the arrays from which to choose `y` can be enumerated easily.  `{ 0: [1,2,3,4], 1: [0,2,3,4], ...}`

Comment: score: 6421931, awesome!

Comment: @TomFan - curious about whether my idea helps much (object lookup, vs 1 shuffle step). If you feel like it, pls post score for that idea here.

Comment: replace:
a = Math.random() * 5 | 0,
b = Math.random() * 4 | 0,

The score is 6579393, faster

Comment: @danh for such a small number of possibilities (there are only different 20 pairs) you could also enumerate all of them beforehand like `[[0,1],[0,2], ..., [1,0],[1,2],...,[5,4]]` and then in the loop just select one of the pairs randomly. Depending on on how many different pairs there are, how many values you need and what random generator you are using, this might also be faster. But again, this has to be determined by a benchmark